# How can be sure if a user is coming from a specified website in only one HTTP GET request?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, security, asp.net-core, iis, https

I have 10 websites hosting in my IIS. A user clicks on a link in `site 1`, the **secret value** generated in server-side (of `site 1`), then I want to send this **secret value** (encrypt or hash) in URL (query string) to `central site` and decrypt/validate the value there, to be sure a user is coming from `site 1` to proceed (and not from another websites).

I think it won't be something fixed string so users can make this URL themselves:
`https://centralSite.com/process?param1=....&param2=....&source_website=site1`

It should be something like a **one-time dynamic generated** token.

My question is :

1. Can I achieve this situation in only **ONE** `HTTP GET` request?
2. Should I use encryption/decryption or hashing/validating (all server-side)?

P.S: I can't use POST or other HTTP verbs here.

P.S: I know about `HTTP referrer`, but it can be spoofed or be null in some situations.

P.S: All websites are serving on HTTPS protocol.

Comment: you could use iis request filtering rule to implement your requirement https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/validation

Comment: If you generated the secret value in server-side in `site 1`, then how about you also send that particular hash value to the `central site` or some key-value cache like **Redis**. On the other hand, when handling requests in the central site, you look up that hashed value from Redis. If such value exist, it proves the incoming hash is a valid one.